# Why jQuery toggle function changes the width of my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a button which I want to use for switching between two divs, hiding one, and showing another. The first div shows alright, but when the switch happens, and the second div is shown, its width is minimized, and its not the same.

```
<button id="flipGraphs">Change</button>
```

My divs are the following:

```
<div class="graph hidden"><%= line_chart @weekly_graph %></div>
<div class="graph"><%= line_chart @daily_graph %></div>
```

This is jQuery code:

```
<script>     
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#flipGraphs').click(function(){
      $('.graph').toggle();         
    });     
  }); 
</script>
```

How can I eliminate this problem, and make the two graphs (divs) show with the normal width, and not get affected by the toggle funcion?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: [Can you reproduce the problem?](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Do you have css defining the width you're looking for?

Comment: @ElliotM, I am defining style, but when toggle function is applied clicking the button, every style that defines width or height is ignored for that same div. Its weird.

Comment: @undefined, its hard to reproduce the problem, since the divs hold some graph functions using rails gems, but they are not the problem, coz i experimented with them, in my opinions its all about finding a 'hack' to make the div hold the style after the function is called ...but i dont know why

Comment: I'd recommend making a jsfiddle to replicate the issue

Comment: @ElliotM I think that this is not a problem with the JS or the HTML/CSS, the problem starts when im using the ChartKick gem with rails, and I cant replicate that issue with jsfiddle ...

Answer (score 0):

In your css give it a fixed width. e.g:

```
div.graph { width: 500px;}
```

or as an inline style:

```
<div class="graph hidden" style="width: 500px;"><%= line_chart @weekly_graph %></div>
<div class="graph" style="width: 500px;"><%= line_chart @daily_graph %></div>
```

Find a width that suits you best and where it doesn't alter the width anymore.

Comment: I tried that even before, it seems logical to work, but it doesnt, it seems like the toggle function just ignores every style that is applied to the hidden div after it is displayed.

Comment: @uklp could something be overwriting the width attribute? Maybe the function/event that renders the graph? You could try creating a container div and applying the style to it and also add an overflow: hidden; to the container div aswell.

Comment: @uklp or try adding the `!important` flag. So it would be like `width: 500px !important;`

Comment: I tried almost everything what you suggested, it just ignores it in the same manner, its getting a huge headache ...

Answer (score 0):

It may because of the content in the div, if you don't want to change the width just add width  in graph class.

```
.graph {
    width : 200px;//depends on your data
}
```

Comment: I tried that even before, it seems logical to work, but it doesnt, it seems like the toggle function just ignores every style that is applied to the hidden div after it is displayed.